# ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage: The type initializer for 'DotNet.Basics.IO.SystemIoPath' threw an exception

Tags: azure-toolkit

I am trying to convert the Publishing Service Module to a WDP, but I am receiving this error. I have searched and do not see a solution that applies to the Sitecore Azure Toolkit

```
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage: The type initializer for 'DotNet.Basics.IO.SystemIoPath' threw an exception.
```

My PowerShell (running PowerShell 7 in admin mode after loading both the module and dll is as follows. I have dacpac installed):

```
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path "C:\Sitecore Azure Toolkit\SitecorePublishingModule1020rev00631.zip" -Destination "C:\Sitecore Azure Toolkit" -force -verbose
```

Comment: Have you tried running in Windows PowerShell 5.1?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWest, I am trying that now.

Comment: It is not letting me install the dll in 5.1 Import-Module "C:\Sitecore Azure Toolkit\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.7.0-r02533.1285\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll" -Verbose

Comment: Import-Module .\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Sitecore Azure Toolkit\Sitecore Azure Toolkit
2.7.0-r02533.1285\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem while attempting to convert my Sitecore package to an SCWDP package. The issue appeared when running the command in `Windows PowerShell 7`. However, I found that running the same command in `PowerShell 5.1` resolved the problem.